# Show/Hide one User Control from another

Tags: c#, winforms

I am tinkering around with User Controls and I've found myself stumped. My form has 2 User Controls, a TitleScreen and a MainScreen. I need for the TitleScreen to be visible when the program runs and then invisible when the "new game" button is clicked, at which point the MainScreen needs to be visible. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this.

FormMain.cs

```
    #region Property Region

    public UserControls.MainScreen ControlMainScreen
    {
        get { return controlMainScreen; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor Region

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        controlMainScreen.Visible = false;
    }

    #endregion
```

TitleScreen.cs

```
    public void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        FormMain.ControlMainScreen.Visible = true;
    }
```

Obviously it doesn't work, but I've tried everything that I know how to do. I also have no clue how to make controlMainScreen static since I didn't actually make the declaration (VS did). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens right now?

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non-static field..." pointing to the second to last line in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ParentForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform.aspx) which is a property on `UserControl` to get a reference to the parent form.

```
((YourFormsExactType)(this.ParentForm)).ControlMainScreen.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I still get an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field..." referring to ControlMainScreen.

Comment: uh sorry, you'll have to cast `ParentForm` to your form's exact type.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: if your class definition is something like `public partial class Form1 : Form { }`, you will need to cast it to `Form1` since that is the type the property exists on.

Answer (score 1):

Add a user control on the Win project and then dynamically add to the Form.

Here is the code:

```
public Show_hideControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Adding First User control
    Main _main = new Main();        

    panel1.Controls.Add(_main);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //removing already added user control
   panel1.Controls.Clear();            
   //Adding second user control
   Alternative _alter = new Alternative();
   panel1.Controls.Add(_alter);
}
```